# Is it possible to calculate only the nth order Taylor/power series coefficient in Maxima?

Tags: maxima, taylor-series

Say I have a power series s3 made up of some product of integer powers of other power series:

```
s1: sum (c1[i]*x^i, i, 1, inf);
s2: sum (c2[i]*x^i, i, 1, inf);
deftaylor(f(x), s1^2 * s2);
s3: powerseries(f(x), x, 0);
```

And I want to know the coefficient of x^1000 in s3 without having to calculate the first 999 terms.

Is there a good way to do this in Maxima?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but possibly `ratcoef` is applicable here. If you don't get a workable answer here, try the maxima-discuss mailing list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: It doesn't do it. I ended up writing my own method.